# Is cm10 compatible with cwm 5.0.2.8 on huawei u8160 ?

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, compatibility, huawei-u8160, boot-loop

I have a Huawei u8160 with CWM 5.0.2.8 .I have tried to flash cm10 using CWM 5.0.2.8 but it boot loops.I have waited for 20 minutes for it to boot ,but it didn't.

I've seen this [discussion](http://androidforums.com/one-s-all-things-root/607753-cm-10-boot-loop.html) about cm10 boot looping and I did flash it using the same way that worked with him ,boot looped.And this [discussion](http://www.nexustablets.net/forum/nexus-tablet-hacking-mods/1095-help-im-bootlooping-yikes.html) too ,but CWM 6 isn't compatible with my phone.

So, I am asking here ,What can I do to make it boot or it's not compatible?